# Does order of columns matter in data.table indexing (setkey)?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a question about indexing `data.table` objects.

```
setkey(data, A, B)
data[, C:=length(unique(B, na.rm=T)), by=A]
```

I was wondering should I change the order of index to

```
setkey(data, B, A)
```

increase the speed. Or are they same? And how should I index for

```
data[c>=3, D:=sum(A), by=B]
```

Comment: You can test it using `library(microbenchmark)`.   In the `devel` version you can use `uniqueN` instead of `length(unique`..

Comment: You could test it yourself using the `microbenchmark` package. But AFAIK the key won't matter for this type of operation; it's used for fast selection using the `i` parameter.

Comment: I did test with `micorbenchmark`, but got mixed results on a trivial function & small data. So I thought I would ask authors or others who might have noticed a difference.

Comment: For small data, benchmark is not useful.  You need to create a big dataset (around 1e6 rows or more ) and test it.

Comment: @akrun to be fair, `uniqueN` doesn't accept an `na.rm=T` argument; it's still faster to use, see my answer in a moment

Comment: @MichaelChirico `unique` doesn't have `na.rm=TRUE` argument either.  `unique(c('x', 'x', NA), na.rm=TRUE)#
[1] "x" NA`

Comment: fair enough, didn't realize it's just being passed through `...` and ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your `length(unique(B, na.rm = T))` bit isn't doing what you think it is--`na.rm = TRUE` is not an argument to `unique`, it's being passed to `...` and ignored (thanks @akrun for pointing this out). Probably the best way to get what you want out of that is to run `uniqueN(na.omit(B))`.

With that in mind, I ran 9 (=3x3) benchmarks comparing the speed of (a slightly beefed up version of) the code you suggested, varying the order of keying: `(B,A)`, `(A,B)`, or nothing (`X`). For example, the `BAX` function referred to below is:

```
BAX <- function(){
  data <- data.table(A = sample(50, size = 1e6, T),
                     B = sample(c(1:150000, NA), size = 1e6, T))
  setkey(data, B, A)
  data[ , C := uniqueN(na.omit(B)), by = A]
  data[C >= 18500, D := sum(A), by = B]
}
```

Here is the result of 200 repetitions of each arrangement:

```
> microbenchmark(times = 200L,
                 XX(), XAB(), XBA(), ABX(), ABAB(),
                 ABBA(), BAX(), BAAB(), BABA())
Unit: milliseconds
   expr       min        lq     mean    median       uq      max neval    cld
   XX()  70.05867  73.66665 105.2628  96.55443 116.5883 213.2926   200 a     
  XAB() 112.52981 121.91760 161.2687 157.66455 172.6626 370.4791   200     ef
  XBA() 112.56648 122.65417 165.9513 158.96873 174.6038 406.3392   200      f
  ABX()  79.59582  82.33355 110.8462 101.04939 125.0158 198.1082   200 a     
 ABAB()  83.81686  90.40803 123.1391 126.94853 132.0878 182.0694   200  b    
 ABBA() 112.50687 117.68602 151.8467 155.72603 161.2123 228.5776   200    de 
  BAX()  85.82144  93.87965 134.5259 130.40824 146.1559 263.9083   200  bc   
 BAAB() 100.48214 105.35192 150.9692 146.76173 156.0230 392.4626   200    de 
 BABA()  93.29706 104.70251 142.8426 138.12848 149.1106 279.4645   200   cd
```

From this simple example, then, your best options are: don't key the table (there appear to be minimal gains from pre-sorting), or key by `(A,B)` first and leave it.

The reverse--key by `(B,A)` first and leave it--also performs pretty well. Given this, I'm actually pretty surprised how poorly `XBA` performed.

---

If you're wondering *why* it seems to be so fast without keying, it's basically that all keying does, for what you're trying to do, is pre-sort the data; this only improves speed minimally in a given operation, but having to re-key in-between operations is a cost. In the manual's parlance, this is a *keyed by* compared with an *ad hoc by*:

> When `by` contains the first n columns of `x`'s key, we call this a keyed by. In a **keyed by** the groups appear contiguously in RAM and memory is copied in bulk internally, for extra speed. Otherwise, we call it an **ad hoc by**. Ad hoc by is still many times faster than tapply, for example, but just not as fast as keyed by when datasets are very large, in particular when the size of each group is large. Not to be confused with `keyby`= defined below.

The real speed advantages of keying are for subsetting and merging--for operations like yours I've found *ad hoc* bys to be perfectly satisfactory.

Comment: Thank you for your well explained answer. I am bit surprised that I don't need to use any indexing for these operations. Instead of `length(unique(B))-any(is.na(B))`, how about if we use `length(unique(na.omit(B)))`? It might take some serious computation in my opinion. I really appreciate your detailed answer. Thank you!

Comment: I added a quote from the manual for extra clarity on this point.

Comment: and indeed `na.omit` is the much better choice.